# nock handles fetch req but does not prevent http call

Tags: javascript, testing, fetch, jestjs, nock

I am using `nock` to intercept a `fetch` call to https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://youtu.be/m4hklkGvTGQ . Like so:

```
it(`properly responds to YouTube URL ${url}`, async () => {
    nock('https://www.youtube.com')
        .get('/oembed')
        .query(true)
        .reply(200, remoteResponse);
    const youTube = new YouTube(url);
    const response = await youTube.getResponse(); // this contains the fetch call
    expect(response).toEqual(expectedResponse);
    nock.restore();
});
```

I see that `nock` properly intercepts my `fetch` because

- If I change the `remoteResponse` (see line `5`, `.reply(200, remoteResponse)` my tests behave / fail as expected
- If I change the intercepting url from `https://www.youtube.com` to `https://www.sometingelse.com`, `nock` tells me it did not catch a fetch request.

However, if I switch off my WiFi and run my tests I can see that my application warns me about a failed HTTP request:

> request to https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4hklkGvTGQ failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.youtube.com www.youtube.com:443

Also, when I run my tests, they take about 1 second (which already seems long), when I turn of my WiFi, they are done immediately.

I wonder why there are still http requests

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I my code i was calling `nock.restore();` and my code was async. I am guessing that I was restoring the nock mocks while my other tests were running. However, removing `nock.restore();` did the trick and because nock always intercepts a single call only it's fine.